# For a Service Principal which permission to give to use command Get-AzNetworkServiceTag?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I create successfully a ServicePrincipal (SP) in AzureAD and able to do a lot of stull like {Connect to Azure, Create resource, etc...}

I need my SP to use command *Get-AzNetworkServiceTag* but it always return empty values.
When I try command command *Get-AzNetworkServiceTag* with my own account I get expected result. I believe problem come from permission and your help is very welcome to set least privilege.
My current permissions looks like:[image]

Do you know which one should I use ?
Alternative question is what is best practices to determine permissions based on powershell command ? Although permissions could name to determine there is so many that it's difficult to choose correct one. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `Get-AzNetworkServiceTag` essentially calls the Azure Management REST API - [`Service Tags - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/servicetags/list), it is not related to Azure AD, to solve the issue, you need to assign the [Azure RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)(not Azure AD admin role) to your service principal.

To solve the issue, the easiest way is to assign the built-in role e.g. `Reader`, `Contributor` to your service principal at the `subscription` scope. But if you want to the
*least privilege*, your option is to [create a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) then use it, you could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to your subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add custom role`, follow the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Then skip the `Permissions`, in the `JSON`, click `Edit`, add `Microsoft.Network/*/read` to `actions` -> Next and create it.

[image]

After creating the custom role, wait for a while, navigate to the `Access control (IAM)` -> add the custom role to your service principal.

[image]

In conclusion, the `Microsoft.Network/*/read` action permission is the least privilege in this case, after giving the role, it will work fine.

[image]

> Alternative question is what is best practice to determine permissions based on powershell command?

You just need to know what does the command do, then find the operation in the [Azure resource provider operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations), in this case, there is no such operation like `Microsoft.Network/serviceTags/read`, so we need to use `Microsoft.Network/*/read` at least.

Comment: Again Joy Wang, you make my day and all these screenshot are so useful. Hope it can help other member of this community. I would like a precision as I am not sur to distinguish solution based on 'Role' and 'custom role'. The way you did for custom role is to go first to Subscription > IAM then add custom role with */read  permissions. What is the difference with Role reader restricted to subscription scope ?

Comment: @terry `*/read` is different from `Microsoft.Network/*/read`, the first one can read all the resources, the second one can just read the resource which belongs to the `Microsoft.Network` provider, in your case, `Microsoft.Network/*/read` is enough, built-in roles are the predefined roles by azure, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

Comment: Oh my bad i missed the word Microsoft.Network/*/read ahahahah sorry. Need to change my glasses.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because Powershell cmdlet works differently than compared to MS Graph. Instead of permissions, Powershell require roles to do this operations. Please add Global Administrator role to your service principle and then try the `Connect-AzAccount` so that, the issue will be fixed.

For more details, you may refer to [Assigning administrator roles in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles).